# OC4J 9.0.4.1 Connection Pool and Datasource

Tags: oracle, datasource, oc4j

I would need to connection to Oracle database via connection pool. Please correct me IF I am wrong that I only need to modify/add the datasources in data-sources.xml.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes thats right, and instructions are at http://download-west.oracle.com/otn_hosted_doc/jdeveloper/904preview/packaging_deploying/dep_adatasources.html